# vector of pairs initialization in C++

Tags: c++, vector

In competitive programming, I see people initializing vector of pairs like below:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> ii;
typedef vector<ii> vii;

vector<vii> AL;
int main(){
  int V, E; scanf("%d %d", &V, &E);
  AL.assign(V, vii());
}
```

I want to ask about `AL.assign(V, vii());` I know that it is going to have `V` pairs in `AL`, but what's the meaning of `vii()` here?

Comment: See `std::vector::assign` form (1) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign).  It's the `value`.

Comment: `vii()` constructs a temporary variable that will be used in the `assign` method and then go out of scope. Fortunately a copy is made of the temporary (assuming the compiler doesn't do some time-saving trickery) so `AL` isn't left referring to dead space.

Comment: Side note: Competition code's not the easiest stuff to learn from. It's intended to be written fast and run once. Comprehensibility is way down on the competitor's priority list.

Comment: Read and learn: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2752075), [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/2752075). Also prefer `using` to `typedef`, e.g. `using ii = pair<int, int>;`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ref](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/):

> `void assign (size_type n, const value_type& val);`
>
> The new contents are n elements, each initialized  to a copy of `val`.
>
> `val`
>
> Value to fill the container with. Each of the n elements in the
> container will be initialized to a copy of this value. Member type
> value_type is the type of the elements in the container, defined in
> vector as an alias of its first template parameter (T).

As @user4581301 commented: "`vii()` constructs a temporary variable that will be used in the assign method and then go out of scope. Fortunately a copy is made of the temporary (assuming the compiler doesn't do some time-saving trickery) so `AL` isn't left referring to dead space".

Answer (score 0):

In

```
AL.assign(V, vii());
```

`vii()` executes the `std::vector` [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) to provide a [temporary object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) to be used as a template (English term, not a C++ `template`) by `std::vector::insert`. This temporary will effectively be copied `V` times, filling `AL` up  with `V` `vector`s of `pair`s, and then it will go out of scope.